# Measuring mass zero G

Tags: mass, measurements, instrument

I work for a company that produces (among other things) a microbalance that can measure mass/weight from around 100ng to 100mg ie it is accurate over 6 orders of magnitude. However, this relies on gravity acting as a counterforce to a computer controlled magnetic field.

Has anyone created a technique that can measure mass over such a wide range in freefall (zero G)? What do they use on the ISS? The only method I can imagine would be something involving vibration and/or springs, whether micro or macro.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put the item in a centrifuge to simulate gravity.

Comment: The major problem is accuracy. I suspect it would be exceedingly difficult to design such a device that is compact. Putting an existing microbalance in a centrifuge and compensating for Coriolis etc might be do-able but it goes from being a small box to something the size of a fridge. That in turn needs to be held in position in zero G